# Couchbase with docker: maximum allowed quota for the node is 368MB error although docker has 3GB of ram

Tags: docker, couchbase

For education I try to run a couchbase from docker on a t3a.nano aws instance (512MB).

https://docs.couchbase.com/server/5.1/install/getting-started-docker.html

Just at the beginning, at Couchbase > New Cluster > Configure I get

***insufficient memory to satisfy memory quota for the services (requested quota is 1024MB, maximum allowed quota for the node is 368MB)***

I added 2GB of swap to host aws vm. And tried running docker container with

-m 2048m --memory-swap 3000m

but it doesn't help.

Whre is the problem? Docker vm has memory set on cmd. How can I deceive docker or couchbase about available memory ?
(I don't mind swapping, I just wanna play with it).

[image]

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-11 ~]$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           461M        322M         15M        156K        122M        127M
Swap:          2,0G         87M        1,9G
```

Comment: Would you mind posting a screenshot of the configuration screen that's showing this error?

Comment: @MatthewGroves I added a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase the VM RAM. Per default it's 1Go.
To do this, go to the VirtualBox interface, stop the VM and modify RAM.